# How to apply Hibernate patch

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing problem running a native SQL query in Hibernate 3.I googled and found its a bug which was fixed in Hibernate 4.1.3. It also has an attachment of a patch file.This is the link:
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2697

I want to apply that patch to my existing hibernate version.Can anybody suggest how I can achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more information if the answer below isn't appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the old hibernate jar or maven dependency xml with the new one.

For instance, in maven say you have...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Change this too....

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Or replace the jar in your build path, you can get the jars from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.1.10.Final/)

Comment: Which will not just apply that patch, but all changes done to hibernate since the old version.

Comment: Still, seing that hibernate 3 is no longer maintained, this might be the best solution.